# How to do SELECT DISTINCT with LINQ

Tags: linq, select, distinct

How to do this SQL Query with LINQ: `Select Distinct(ColumnB) From TableX` ?

Im trying to do womething like that but doesn't work:

```
var years = _uow.TimeTable.AsQueryable();
years.Select(c => new { c.Year }).GroupBy(c => c.Year);
return years.ToList();
```

Thank You!!

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348456.aspx)() LINQ method:

```
return years.Select(c => c.Year).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

See below. After selecting and grouping.

```
 return years.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: I think the select and the grouping is a part of its attempt to have a distinct.